# Check if slug item path has a parent using split (arrays)

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to find out if the second slug is a parent of the first one:

```
"questions/ask" and "questions"
```

I do not want to use String.startsWith because:
`"questions/ask" and "question" must not pass.` *Solution for this case in the comments.

> Can you guys help me out with a cleaner solution for this function in
>   ES6?

```js
const a = ["ask", "questions"];
const c = ["questions", "ask", "anything"];

const b = ["questions"];

console.log(arrayStartsWith(b, a)); //`questions` is not the first element
console.log(arrayStartsWith(b, c)); //`questions` is present in sequence

function arrayStartsWith(needleArray, haystackArray) {

    if(haystackArray.length < needleArray.length) {
        return false;
    }

    for(let i = 0; i < needleArray.length; i++) {
        if(haystackArray[i] !== needleArray[i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;

}
```

Comment: How about `(a+"/").startsWith(b+"/")`? (If your paths can end with slashes, you need to normalise them first for that of course)

Comment: Why didn't I think about this... Thank you!

Comment: You will need only one index variable (not `i` and `j`), you can use an early return for the length comparison to reduce indentation, and you should name the function `arrayStartsWith`, but apart from that your approach is just fine.

Comment: I have updated the question with your suggestions :)